# How to align textview at the bottom of the screen inside a scroll view android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I am designing a login screen having following items

> 1. Logo
> 2. User Name
> 3. Password
>      4.Login Button
> 4. Copyright

Below is the layout I have tried to implement the same

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
style="@style/ActivityStyle"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".abc.ui.main.login.view.LoginActivity">
<!-- Login progress -->
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_abc_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/abc_logo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/img_abc_logo"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"

            android:orientation="vertical">


            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_user_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/fontColor"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/copy_right_font_color" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/fontColor"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/copy_right_font_color" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_login"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:height="55dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    style="@style/CopyRightTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/copy_right_text" />
```

**My requirement**

> 1. Log should be at the top
> 2. User name ,password and login button should be at the center of screen
> 3. Copyright at the bottom

**Problem faced**

1. Since I am using scroll view I am not able to fill the height . I tried with android:fillViewport="true" but my scroll disappear.So I am not able to place login input and button to center
2. Copyright info is coming above login button when key board appear

Comment: remove `android:paddingTop="30dp"`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya : Tried but keyboard push it above login button

Comment: your parent RL is `android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" ` ??

Comment: @rahul: See my answer bellow it will  defiantly works in your case.

Comment: @SuhasBachewar Thanks a lot it worked in portrait but in landscape it is staying fixed at bottom .

Comment: @SuhasBachewar can you please check my requirement mentioned in my description and could you please give me some tips to design the same taking both orientation into consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your activity in side onCreate Method

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

or 
In Manifest at your activty:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: Thanks Suhas This worked in portrait but in landscape it is staying fixed at bottom . What is the best practice to handle the above mentioned scenario .

Comment: as you mentioned you need "copyright Textview" at bottom of screen in case of Landscape it works same, here the height of screen calculated and according to it Relative layout sets the view. due to less height it wont show space between Login button & Copyright Textview. Still you need space between them you have to detect the orientation and apply programmatically.

Comment: Yes my confusion is clear thanks for the explanation . But my problem is not solved . I tried to put every thing inside scrollView and I set android:fillViewport="true"  . Here I can place logo at top, login input and button block at center and copyright info at the bottom . It solved my problem but issue is that scroll disappears and item getting overlapped

Answer (score 0):

In your TextView Remove

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

add

```
 android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
```

TextView  move inside the RelativeLayout.like this

```
<TextView
style="@style/CopyRightTextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:paddingTop="30dp"
android:text="@string/copy_right_text" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: TextView  move to top of the screen

Comment: check you placed in textview after </LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

as you are saying inside scrollview put it inside `relative layout`

```
    <TextView
        style="@style/CopyRightTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"

        android:text="@string/copy_right_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```